# Is it possible to use view inflator to inflate individual items?

Tags: java, android, listview, view

Right now I am using a custom list view and I am inflating an xml file to be viewed. I wanted to inflate the layout to have different inflations depending on the position.

```
public View getView(int position,View v,ViewGroup parent) {
    if (v == null) {
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,null);

        final TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
    }
```

Grid item is what i am inflating. I want to inflate several different items depending on the position while still keeping the text view. Currently to do this I have an image inside grid_item that I am changing, but I would rather do it this way.

Comment: Do you mean you want to inflate a different xml based on the position?  What exactly do you mean by "inflate several different items"?

Comment: Yes, inflate a different xml based on the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so if you want to inflate a different xml based on the position then just use some old school code I would say, something like

```
if (v == null) {
    if(position < 5){//whatever condition you want here    
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,null);
    }
    else{
        v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item2,null);
    }
}

final TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
tv.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
```

then just make sure to name the text field in all of your xmls grid_text and you are good to go.

Comment: v = li.inflate ... will inflate the whole view. Not just part of it, right?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see what you mean by inflating "part" of it.  As far as I know you can only inflate a complete xml.  Once it is inflated you can grab any part of it that you want.

Does my answer not give you the solution you need?  If not do you maybe have a visual of what you need to accomplish to better understand the issue?

Comment: Okay I figured it out! This was definitely helpful!

Comment: glad to help, also make sure to name the textview the same in all the xmls and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

create  different xml for different position

```
 or
```

create a xml with container (Linearlayout  only) and add view at run time as per position

Comment: I have different xmls for different positions, but how would I do that. I looked online and people said it wasn't possible, but it should be.

Comment: so how many different layouts are there and what is criteria for using differnt layouts (means which element need which layout)

Comment: there are four different layouts. And currently I have an array of four numbers that I am going to use to set each indv. position.

Comment: can use if (v == null) { switch(position%4) case 1:  v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item,null); break  v = li.inflate(R.layout.grid_item2,null);... and nut to forgot set default there

Comment: Yes, but that will inflate the whole list view with the same xml file. But I want different xmls in the same list view.

Comment: no I use switch so every 4th element will inflate the different xml